# How do I break X vs. How do I defend X?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-question, black-hat

Do we care to have questions similar to [Exploiting PHP via GET params](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36538)?

Why or why not?

Comment: I think the question is okay. It might be based on wrong assumptions, but other people will have them, too. So the answers will be helpful for them. A more specific subject might be helpful, but I don't have a good idea at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think, based on the lengthy discussion previously held, this type of question does provide value to both attackers and defenders, so is probably on topic here.

This question is nicely specific, asking for analysis of a particular type of attack so I think it is okay here - I understand your point that as it is currently worded it is obviously aimed at attack, but even if it was changed to be aimed at defence it wouldn't be a huge stretch to see the other side.

If it was a 'givmetehkoedz' question it would obviously be off topic, but I think that fragments like this are of value to defenders and are a learning opportunity.